# How to coax 8-sec shutter on aperture prio film cam?

Tags: film, shutter-speed, 35mm, yashica

Camera: [Yashica Electro 35 cc](https://camerapedia.fandom.com/wiki/Yashica_Electro_CC)

Hi guys!

Multiple records about my camera model indicate that it has a shutter speed range of 1/250 to 8sec.

However, I recently tried to photograph an orange streelit frontage using the biggest f stop (f1.8). It ended up quite underexposed, with only the streetlight bulb showing in the negative. I thought the camera would automatically use a long exposure. The ASA tab was set to 400.

My thought is, maybe I should crank the ASA to the lowest value of 25. Will I get the 8 seconds?

More background info:
According to records online, the camera will use a 1/30 shutter at the nearest f that the under-exposure indicator lamp comes off. If a shot is taken with the under-exposure indicator remaining, then the camera will then a tripod must be used as the camera will "select the appropriate shutterspeed".

Comment: How do you know the camera did not use an eight second exposure to get the underexposed negative? What type and speed film was actually in the camera?

Comment: Well, just based on how I remember it sounding. It definitely wasn't a long exposure shot. Fujicolor Superia xtra 400.

Comment: You could try to do a "double, multiple exposure", If you can. On a tripod, Take one exposure,  press the film rewind button on the bottom of the camera (***do not rewind the film***) and then actuate the film advance lever. This resets the shutter without advancing the film. Now you can take another, 8sec exposure.  You will need a light meter to read the scene so you know how long of an exposure you need for the aperture that  you have set. You will need to adjust the development time of your film to reflect the asa you needed to set the light meter to in order to get a workable time.

Comment: @AlaskaMan this is another technique i might explore. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, your camera does not allow for a shutter speed selection and is always on Aperture-Priority?

Cool. You've already discovered, it seems, that you can modify the ASA/ISO/FilmSpeed setting to encourage shutter speeds that would normally fall outside of the metered parameter for the film actually in the camera.

But, if your goal is to simply run-out the timer for an exposure and to use all 30s every time, then all you need to do is cover the meter with something opaque. You'll reduce the light into the meter so much that the camera enables a 30s exposure because, well, that's the best it can do.

Comment: Yes that would indeed be less mechanical. Probably a snippet of opaque tape. I can imagine that the ASA tab on this camera wasn't meant to be fudged for every shot.

Answer (score 1):

already got the answer by trying it out myself. Lowering the ASA is practically proxy for a longer shutter speed in this camera.

Funny that a blogger already mentions this. What nobody has mentioned though is that the longest shutter speed on this Yashica Electro 35cc is not 8s or 16s. It's 30 seconds!

Now, I have to take a few more evening experiment shots so I have more benchmarks when I load my next roll.

Comment: I read something, somewhere, about taking the battery out to facilitate longer exposures or something like that. ??

Comment: @AlaskaMan Now that seems like a very analog way of going about things.  One thing that most cameras with other than direct manual controls won't do is changing aperture or focus while exposing, for more interesting bokeh effects.  Sometimes I'd like a primitive programmable interface into the firmware to allow for such experimentation...